# Can two compositions own the same object?

Tags: oop, uml, composition, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to make a class diagram for an Online Auction System and I'm having this problem. Bids belong to both the Auction and the Buyer (Correct me if i'm wrong). So can I say that User is composed of bid AND auction is composed of Bid or is this against the rules of UML?  I'm confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### In general

The term composition is ambiguous and this explains your confusion:

- In OOP, [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) means to use an object in another one.
- In UML, [composition](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html?context=class-diagrams) is a special kind of association that represents a part-whole relationship,  with an exclusive ownership of the parts by the whole.

So in the UML sense, it is not possible to have an object that is part of two different compositions, because the ownership would no longer be exclusive.  But you could use the object in several [aggregations](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html), which are a whole-part relations allowing a shared ownership.

In the OOP sense, there is no problem of having the same object used in (or using)  several compositions.  The object composition corresponds to a [navigable](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability) UML [association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html?context=class-diagrams).

#### In your practical case

The situation is straight forward:  A `Bid` has one `Buyer`, a `Buyer` may have several `Bids`, and an `Auction` has several `Bids`.  You can model this with simple associations:

[image]

You could alternatively use an aggregation here, since one could argue that there is a whole-part relation between an `Auction` and the corresponding `Bids` (personally, I wouldn't see it like this):

[image]

You should however not see an aggregation on the other side, because there is no real whole-part relation between a `Buyer` and a `Bid`:  a `Buyer` is not "made of several `Bids`".

#### Additional remarks

You could use also an association class here.  But it's not required. And the semantic would be different:  it would mean that there is a `Bid` association between a `Buyer` and an `Auction`:

- Technically speaking, you'd still have three classes.
- But the focus is different:  the `Bid` is accessory to the `Buyer` and the `Auction` and cannot exist on its own (e.g. if the buyer disappears)

Comment: I don't think the claim "at most one Bid per Buyer on an Auction" is correct for association classes. If I have a [*]--[*] association between Buyer and Auction, wouldn't that allow for multiple bids per buyer in an Action?

Comment: @GeertBellekens with a proper class you can. But with an association class I don't think, because of the semantic reasons that the association doesn't have an identity and is only there to give properties to a link. But it's worth cross-checking in UML std. If you find any evidence of the contrary, I'm ready to adjust my additional remark.

Comment: See the note at page 199: _NOTE. Even when all ends of the AssociationClass have isUnique=true, it is possible to have several instances associating the same set of instances of the end Classes._

Comment: @GeertBellekens thanks for this enriching info ! I've adjusted the wording accordingly

Comment: AssociationClasses are interesting, when you want to define that each pair of Auction and Buyer has only one bid. I don't think this is desired here. Therefore the attributes on both sides would need to have the property {non unique}. Then the same semantics can be expressed with a normal Class Bid.

Comment: Composition also means that the Composite is responsible for the existence of its parts. I think it makes sense here to make the Auction responsible for the bids.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer thanks for your additional insight on the association class. For the composition, I tend to be prudent. I'd intuitively not see Auction as exclusive owner of the Bid: you could still want to see the bidding history of a buyer, even after an auction was deleted because the seller close her account. But I fully agree that this is debatable and that there is room for discussion; this should be clarified further by OP with the stakeholders.

Comment: @Geert: You are right in pointing out that an AssociationClass doesn't define unique links any more. In fact it lost its uniqueness feature in UML 2.5. I think this was an error, because this was the only distinguishing feature of it. It makes AssociationClasses obsolete, because they can now always be replaced with an intermediate class.

Answer (score 2):

Have you learned about association classes in UML? They represent an object that is created from the relationship between two other classes, exactly what you are trying to map. There are plenty of contents detailing Association Classes (e.g. [Correct use of an association class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206437/correct-use-of-an-association-class))

That way you shouldn't get confused reading the diagrams (which you were doing correctly btw), it would be clear to you that exists the entity Bid, which exists only associated to both Buyer and Auction.